# Ubuntu SFTP error

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, sftp

I have a custom SFTP server implementation that uses Ganymed SSH codebase for many parts. The server works well with mainstream clients like `FileZilla, Cyberduck, WinSCP, Transmit, OSX SFTP Command`.

But the `Ubuntu SFTP command` fails to connect to the server.

The error is as following:

`hash mismatch
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature incorrect
key_verify failed for server_host_key`

I am providing a detail log of the Ubuntu SFTP client session here:

```
mohammadbhuyan@ubuntu:~$ sftp -v -v -v -P 8020 system:manager@192.168.207.1
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.207.1 [192.168.207.1] port 8020.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Mediaflux_1.0
debug1: no match: Mediaflux_1.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.207.1]:8020
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[192.168.207.1]:8020" from file "/home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: bits set: 994/2048
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 32:62:f2:0a:7d:8a:8c:ec:44:35:6c:e9:e1:c3:e9:60
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.207.1]:8020
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.207.1]:8020
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[192.168.207.1]:8020" from file "/home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[192.168.207.1]:8020" from file "/home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[192.168.207.1]:8020' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mohammadbhuyan/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1005/2048
hash mismatch
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature incorrect
key_verify failed for server_host_key
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

The error seems to be discusses in the following threads:

https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T55895

I am having trouble understanding what actually the issue is? Is this s problem with the server or the Ubuntu client?

My goal is to understand the problem and then if applicable fix it in the server code. SO any discussion welcome.

Regards

Mohammad

Comment: You need to post the code that you need help with. Otherwise, how can anyone know what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Bramer, thanks for your comment.

This is a ubuntu sftp client (shell command) error. Intent of my post is to get an understanding what makes the client get that error. For that the server is irrelevant.

Also event if I wanted to I don't see how providing a large codebase of a SSH/SFTP server ( SSH layer, SFTP layer ) implementation is useful in this case. 

If I knew what part of the server codebase is at fault to make the client fail on that error - then I probably have fixed it myself. 

Thanks,